# What is GCP alias IP(secondary range) and how to use it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So I created a VM with secondary range IP in GCP.

I create this VM with a primary IP `10.10.0.3`, and an alias IP (secondary range) `10.10.0.4`.

Then I created a new VM and found that the new VM has an IP `10.10.0.5`.

I loggin into first VM and did a `ip addr` and can only found ip `10.10.0.3`, there's no `10.10.0.4`.

But I can ping `10.10.0.4`

So what is the alias IP? where can I find it? How to use it? What's the purpose?

Comment: You may want to have a look at this doc: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/alias-ip

Comment: You can define different routing/firewall roule according with 2 different of IP range. But be careful of headaches !